# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic()

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I have a method subscribeToTopic to subscribe users to a location in my app for Firebase notifications.

This method is called when Location is made available to the app (either when app starts & location is available or when a LocationCallback is received). The method is called after the necessary data of the app has been loaded from server.

The app is crashing on opening sometimes at the below line.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(longPCountry);
```

The error that I have received from crashlog from PlayStore is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic (Unknown Source:89)
  at packagename.MapsActivity.subscribeToTopic (MapsActivity.java:1734)
  at packagename.MapsActivity$10.onSuccess (MapsActivity.java:1835)
  at packagename.MapsActivity$10.onSuccess (MapsActivity.java:1831)
  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run (Unknown Source:27)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6809)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is my method

```
public void subscribeToTopic(Location location){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        clientLat = location.getLatitude();
        clientLng = location.getLongitude();
        checkCity();
        List<Address> address = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            address = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address.size()>0) {
            String longPCountry = address.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String clientCity = address.get(0).getLocality();
            String defaultVal = "first";
            String lastTopic = getStringPreference(getString(R.string.pnTopicSubFile),getString(R.string.pnTopicSub),defaultVal);
            if (longPCountry!=null) {
                if (!longPCountry.equals(lastTopic)) {
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(longPCountry);
                    putStringPreference(getString(R.string.pnTopicSubFile),getString(R.string.pnTopicSub),longPCountry);
                    if (!lastTopic.equals("first")){
                        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(lastTopic);
                    }
                }
            }
            String lastCity = getStringPreference(getString(R.string.pnTopicCityFile),getString(R.string.pnTopicCity),defaultVal);
            if (clientCity!=null){
                if (!clientCity.equals(lastCity)){
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(clientCity);
                    putStringPreference(getString(R.string.pnTopicCityFile),getString(R.string.pnTopicCity),clientCity);
                    if (!lastCity.equals("first")){
                        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(lastCity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It has crashed on an Android 8.0 and Android 7.1 device. It has also worked on the same Android versions on other devices.

Can it be related to Firebase token generation?

It crashed on opening the app second time also, by that time surely the Firebase token should be generated.

Appreaciate any help here.

Comment: Have you initialized Firebase on you Application class?

Comment: @PedroMassango can you tell me what you mean by initialization exactly? It is working on other devices so I am assuming the problem is something else?

Comment: Can you show the value of longPCountry?

Comment: @PedroMassango The values are names of states in India, like "Maharashtra", "Gujarat" etc. Where it has worked, I can see the topics on my Firebase console also. I don't call this line if longPCountry is null or if it is the same name as what was sent last time.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the rules of an topic name. Check it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing in the right direction. I tried directly sending the name of the location where it was crashing. Turns out there cannot be a 'space' in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There cannot be 'space' in the name of the string argument of subscribeToTopic() method.

I was using the Android Address API to get the location name and for few locations, the names were like "New York". Removing the spaces before calling the method worked.

```
longPCountry = longPCountry.replace(" ","");
```

The allowed format is [a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}